# Invalid pointer in C program reading file

Tags: c, file, memory

I have a strange problem when running a C program in Linux.
It compiles without any errors, but when I run it I get this error message:

```
*** Error in `./catter': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fffc7953310 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3ee787bc17]
./catter[0x4007d3]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x3ee7821b75]
./catter[0x400589]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 12200149                           /home/sasha/catter
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:09 12200149                           /home/sasha/catter
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:09 12200149                           /home/sasha/catter
01301000-01322000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
30a8200000-30a8215000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 795604                         /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.1-20130603.so.1
30a8215000-30a8414000 ---p 00015000 08:08 795604                         /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.1-20130603.so.1
30a8414000-30a8415000 r--p 00014000 08:08 795604                         /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.1-20130603.so.1
30a8415000-30a8416000 rw-p 00015000 08:08 795604                         /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.1-20130603.so.1
3ee7400000-3ee7421000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 786482                         /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
3ee7620000-3ee7621000 r--p 00020000 08:08 786482                         /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
3ee7621000-3ee7622000 rw-p 00021000 08:08 786482                         /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
3ee7622000-3ee7623000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3ee7800000-3ee79b6000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 786735                         /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
3ee79b6000-3ee7bb6000 ---p 001b6000 08:08 786735                         /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
3ee7bb6000-3ee7bba000 r--p 001b6000 08:08 786735                         /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
3ee7bba000-3ee7bbc000 rw-p 001ba000 08:08 786735                         /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
3ee7bbc000-3ee7bc1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f997a36e000-7f997a371000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f997a392000-7f997a395000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffc7935000-7fffc7956000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffc795c000-7fffc795e000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted
```

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int FILEERROR_ = 0;
char *ReadFile(char *filename, char *permissions)
{
    char output[FileSize(filename) + 1];//1 for a start
    char c;
    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0;
    fp = fopen(filename, permissions);
    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        output[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    char *allo = &output[0];
    return allo;
}
int FileSize(char *filename)
{
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    while(fgetc(fp) != EOF)
    {       
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return i;
}
int main()
{
    char *read = ReadFile("a.out", "r");
    printf("%s", read);
    free(read);
    return 0;
}
```

If this is relevant, I am using Fedora Linux, 64-bit with a GCC C Compiler.

Comment: Start with building with debug information (add the `-g` flag to gcc). Then Valgrind will be able to use that information to print source files and line numbers.

Comment: Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x0000003ee7835a19 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Comment: You don't have a malloc, calloc or realloc. What are you trying to free?

Answer (score 2):

You're returning stack-variables in `ReadFile()`

```
char output[FileSize(filename) + 1];//1 for a start
...
char *allo = &output[0];
return allo;
```

So the returning pointer is pointing to an invalid memory, you should not free it.
Instead, if you really want this, you should allocate memory in it:

```
char* output = (char*)malloc([FileSize(filename) + 1);//1 for a start
...
char *allo = &output[0];
return allo;
```

Then you can free the pointer.
But this is not a suggested way.

A better way is to allocate the memory out of `ReadFile`, and pass the pointer into it. `ReadFile` is only responsible to read and save the content into the pointer. Your `main()` is responsible to allocate and free the memory.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - Controversial practice :-)

Comment: @Abhineet It is only fatal practice in C90. C99 removed "implicit int" for functions without a prototype. However, casting the result of malloc suggests that you don't quite know what you are doing or how the C language works, so I would call it _bad practice_.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Writing `return (allo);` is also harmless practice. Does that mean that it is good practice? No, just like casting the result of malloc, it is superfluous clutter, which originates from insecurity about how the C language actually works.

Comment: I didn't say it is *good*. But saying it's *fatal* is a lie. /off

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation,](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/)

```
void free (void* ptr);
```

**ptr**::

> Pointer to a memory block previously allocated with malloc, calloc or
>   realloc.

So, you should first `malloc` some memory and then call `free`. Also, `output` is local to `ReadFile()`, so, it will die as soon you will exit `ReadFile()`.
You should be doing something like this::

```
char* output = malloc(FileSize(filename) + 1);//1 for a start
/* do stuff */
char *allo = &output[0];
return allo;
```

Comment: @user2332868:: I know but make sure that you never use "typecasting" on malloc in C. It introduces a bug. And it can be fatal at times. Always include <stdlib.h> when using malloc.

Comment: And, ofcourse, you can accept the solution if it worked correctly for you ;-)

Comment: I forgot the only thing I had to change is that you accidentally added a '[' character :).

Comment: @user2332868 - Corrected :-D

Answer (score 1):

The error is with `char output[FileSize(filename) + 1];` line as you are defining output in a function and after the function returns that memory space for output is also freed. So your pointer **allo** points to NULL.

Thus you return NULL and **read** pointer is NULL.

You can try below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int FILEERROR_ = 0;
void ReadFile(char *filename, char *permissions,char* output)
{
//char output[FileSize(filename) + 1];//1 for a start
//char *output = (char*)malloc(FileSize(filename)+1);
char c;
FILE *fp;
int i = 0;
fp = fopen(filename, permissions);
while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    output[i] = c;
    i++;
}
fclose(fp);
//char *allo = &output[0];
//return allo;
}
int FileSize(char *filename)
{
int i = 0;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(filename, "r");
while(fgetc(fp) != EOF)
{
    i++;
}
fclose(fp);
return i;
}
int main()
{
char *read = (char*)malloc(FileSize("a.out")+1);
ReadFile("a.out", "r",read); // passing argument "read" as a pointer
printf("%s", read);
free(read);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *ReadFile(char *filename, char *permissions)
{
    char output[FileSize(filename) + 1];//1 for a start
    char c;
    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0;
    fp = fopen(filename, permissions);
    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        output[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    char *allo = &output[0];
    return allo;
}
```

char output[FileSize(filename) + 1] is stored in static memory so after the function finish execute its instructions, all local variable in static memory will be released , so you do not need to release it. it's better to allocate memory using malloc et then after finish using variable FREE it.